# Checking undefined value not working?

Tags: javascript, null, undefined

I have the following javascript code:

```
var currentIds = localStorage.getItem('currentPairsIds');

if ((typeof currentIds === "undefined") ||
    (currentIds == null))
        $.myNameSpace.currentIDs = new Array(3);
    else
        $.myNameSpace.currentIDs = currentIds.Split(',');
```

I'm debugging with Firebug and although `currentIds` hasn't got any value it always executes `else` statement.

**UPDATE:** 
 I'm getting this value from HTML5 storage.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well that must mean that the value of `currentIds` is not really `undefined`.

Comment: @Pointy: it's undefined. The statement `$.myNameSpace.currentIDs = currentIds.Split(',');` throws an exception.

Comment: Is `currentIds` `"undefined"` or is it `undefined`? `typeof "undefined"` is string.

Comment: currentIds hasn't got any value.

Comment: Either you are stuck in an alternate universe, or the value of currentIds isn't what you think it is.

Comment: @Andrew: I want to check if currentIds hasn't got any value.

Comment: Why not use `try/catch`? is best ... Example: codepen.io/KingRider/pen/dMmKwq

Comment: i found the answer here [Under typeof and undefined in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how I have solved my problem:

```
var currentIds = localStorage.getItem('currentPairsIds');

if ((currentIds === undefined) ||
    (currentIds == null) || (currentIds == "undefined"))
        $.myNameSpace.currentIDs = new Array(3);
    else
        $.myNameSpace.currentIDs = currentIds.split(',');
```

`localStorage.getItem('currentPairsIds');` returns the string `"undefined"`.

There is another error in `Split()` function. The right version is without any capital letter.

Comment: This is wrong, `localStorage.getItem()` does not return the string "undefined", it returns `null`, you only need the `null` check, not the other stuff that you're blindly testing.

Comment: @JuanMendes, i got an undefined and this syntax worked for my problem. In fact, it was the odd `== "undefined"` that caught my problem!

Comment: @DaveA That is because you saved something that was undefined, and local storage converts it into the string "undefined". When saving something into localStorage, you should be careful not to set it to undefined, or null. I would always set it to the empty string instead

Comment: @JuanMendes, i did indeed save invalid data. App is in early development and sloppy things happen. But I don't think the string "undefined" went into memory. But things like this will happen. You can kill yourself with validation, but issues will crawl past you...

Comment: @DaveA `localStorage.setItem('test', undefined)` will cause `localStorage.getItem('test')` to return `'undefined'`, the string. That can easily happen if you set it to a falsy value . That's what you should avoid

Comment: @JuanMendes, of course avoid it. But also test for it. *&!@ will happen

Answer (score 2):

I would use a direct comparison instead of the notoriously odd "typeof" operator:

```js
if ((currentIds === undefined) || (currentIds === null)) {
  //...
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not working because `localStorage.getItem` returns `null` if the item is not defined, it does not return `undefined` http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#dom-storage-getitem

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/Rsu8N/1/

```
var notStored = localStorage.getItem('ffff');

alert(notStored); // null
alert(typeof notStored); // object, yes, null is an object.
```

Therefore you should just be testing

```
alert(notStored === null);
```

Answer (score 0):

---

**[Edit Edit Edit Edit :P]**

---

```
currentIds = "undefined"
```

implies

```
typeof currentIds == "String"
```

Also see, [Detecting Undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property-in-javascript), === isn't necessary for string comparison.

Comment: Your code is correct, the value of currentIDs as you described it doesn't seem to match what you expect it to be, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I've updated my question this line `var currentIds = localStorage.getItem('currentPairsIds');` It's where I'm getting `currentIds` value.

Comment: @VansFannel you are retrieving an array then trying to call split on it, which is undefined.

Comment: Your previous answer is the correct answer. localstorage.getItem returns the string "undefined". I have to check if currentIds == "undefined".

Comment: @Andrew: But I've solved using currentIds == "undefined". Your answer said currentIds = "undefined".

Comment: @VansFannel What I'm saying in my answer is that if currentIDs has a value of "undefined", then typeof will return String, not "undefined". I didn't tell you how to fix that, just what you were doing wrong, which was your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make checking for `undefined` comparing with `==` instead of `===`. 
Example:

```
typeof currentIds == "undefined"
```

This will make sure, the variable is really undefined or not.

Comment: `==` or `===` makes no difference in this case.

Comment: That changes nothing, typeof returns a String.

Answer (score 0):

In my case LocalStorage.getItem() was converting it to "undefined" as string.
I also needed to check if it s "undefined" as a string.

```
var myItem = LocalStorage.getItem('myItem');
if(myItem != "undefined" && myItem != undefined && myItem != null){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if( typeof(varName) != "undefined" && varName !== null )
```

be sure, you use ( " " ) quotes when checking with `typeof()`